# fair scheduling in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

When configuring for fair scheduling in a multiple node setup (master-slave), should the properties be defined in the mapred-site.xml for both the nodes or only in the master node ?
Thanks.

Comment: By default each Hadoop node has its own configuration unless there's a global location from where they are symlinked. I would keep them in sync across the cluster.

Comment: The scheduler configs only apply to the JobTracker (i.e. your 'master'). Tools such as [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cloudera-manager.html) do a decent automatic job of segregating configs by role and keeping them generally neat - with separate client configs and per-role service configs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not need to define properties at more than one locations. If required Hadoop will copy the mapred-site.xml file to the slaves automatically.

If you are running locally then `HADOOP_CONF_DIR/mapred-site.xml` needs to be edited.

And if you are running on Amazon's EMR cluster, then while firinf up the cluster itself you can provide this config file as bootstrap-action and it will be copied in all the nodes. It can be done using cli as follows:

```
ruby elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --plain-output --master-instance-type m1.xlarge --
slave-instance-type m1.xlarge --num-instances 11  --name "Cluster name"  --bootstrap-action 
s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop --args "--mapred-config-file, 
s3://<path-to-conf>/mapred-site-edited.xml"
```

So basically each Hadoop node should have it's own configuration but you should not need to copy it manually to each of them.